# Mysql - balance between amount

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I'm trying to get balance between amount on each row. Basically need to add or subtract the value of previous record field.

Table:

```
+------+------------+---------+---------+
| id   | expiration |  amount | is_paid |
+------+------------+---------+---------+
| 4    | 2014-09-02 |  100.00 |    1    |
| 10   | 2014-09-03 |  200.00 |    1    |
| 35   | 2014-09-03 |  10.32  |    0    |
| 2    | 2014-09-03 |  -32.00 |    1    |
| 1    | 2014-09-04 |  -50.00 |    0    |
| 200  | 2014-09-04 |  400.00 |    1    |
| 30   | 2014-09-05 |  100.00 |    1    |
+------+------------+---------+---------+
```

I would like create a VIEW to compute a balance just in field that is set is_paid=1 and between expiration dates.
Ex:

```
+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| id   | expiration |  amount | is_paid | balance |
+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 4    | 2014-09-02 |  100.00 |    1    |  100.00 |
| 10   | 2014-09-03 |  200.00 |    1    |  300.00 |
| 35   | 2014-09-03 |  10.32  |    0    |  300.00 |
| 2    | 2014-09-03 |  -30.00 |    1    |  270.00 |
| 1    | 2014-09-04 |  -50.00 |    0    |  270.00 |
| 200  | 2014-09-04 |  400.00 |    1    |  670.00 |
| 30   | 2014-09-05 |  100.00 |    1    |  770.00 |
+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you need to put it into a view? this is the select that will do your calculation for you

```
SELECT * , 
       @a := if(is_paid = 1,  @a + amount, @a) as balance
FROM table
CROSS JOIN(SELECT @a := 0)t
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ad732/1)

here is a breakdown of how it works...

pull out what you want from the table, also include a new column called balance..
balance here is the previous row's balance plus the current amount if it is labeled as paid `is_paid`... however if it is not paid then it just repeats the balance.

```
if (condition, true / then, false / else)
```

so if is_paid, then add the previous balance with the current (@a contains the previous rows balance till you reset it with the if statement in the next row) if its not paid then just repeat @a the balance

hope that's helpful

Comment: Nice and quick! Could you add a tiny explanation how does this work?

Comment: basically it does a row by row comparrison and puts in the amount of the previous row and the current row when is paid is 1 or else it just puts in the previous amount.

Comment: @Danatela I just added a demo for you to look at and play around with. btw you have -32.00 in the table and then -30.00 in the expected result for the row where id = 2

Comment: Thanks! I just tried to make my own answer, but yours is better.

Comment: @Danatela thanks :) i also added a brief breakdown of how it works too :)

Comment: Hi John. Tks for reply and help. I tried apply in my full table without result. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abd191/1

Comment: @adrianogf Here don't make it null seems to be messing it up.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abd191/2